# How to mimic jQuery.append() with image links in PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm building a database-backed website that displays thumbnails dynamically based on keyword searches.  Right now, I'm using `jQuery.append()` to create the thumbnails and links based on the searches.  This has the advantage of having the search and results page as one.

For beginning development purposes, this has the advantage of being quick and easy to set up and have reliable results.  But this method relies on the browser for the heavy lifting, and I'd like to optimize this functionality to focus more on the server.  How can I offload this process to the server?

Comment: How many images are you `.append()`ing?

Comment: Anywhere from 1 to ~50.  However, some keywords have more than 400 distinct references.

Comment: 50 images isn't a lot. Do you see any performance impact because of the images?

Comment: are you trying to balance the load between client and server?

Comment: @ianace, thats exactly what I'm trying to do.  Also, I'd like to eventually implement an infinite photostream a la google image search.

Comment: i think the key point here is finding the optimum number that is balanced between the browser and the server; if you tend to make heavier for the browser consider that there are other clients that it should cater to; on the other hand if it becomes browser intensive ie too many dom manipulations, consider the case of smart phones or phones that barely support a full pledged js engine

Comment: Pretty much what I had in mind.  Any ideas on how to implement the server-side balance?

Comment: for starters you have to go for metrics; statistics,benchmarks helps in this area

Comment: but if you just want to to do as what you have asked then i would suggest putting your html files as in an MVC architecture; the html files as the view / template